# Generate a block of serial numbers from SQL Server while handling concurrent connections?

Tags: sql, sql-server, concurrency, transactions

We have an application that has to generate unique sequential serial numbers and store the range in a database. We just need to log the range of numbers, we store the actual ones elsewhere

Basically how it's setup now is we have a simple table with three columns `SequenceStartNumber`, `SequenceEndNumber`, and `AllocatedFor`.

So for example, the rows may look as so :

```
SequenceStartNumber    SequenceEndNumber   AllocatedFor
1                      1000                CustomerXYZ
1001                   2000                CustomerZZY
```

A piece of code will do a query with

```
SELECT MAX(SequenceEndNumber) + 1 AS FirstNumber 
FROM SequenceNumberAllocation
```

The code takes the result of this query, adds on how ever many serial numbers it knows it needs, and performs an insert with

```
INSERT INTO SequenceNumberAllocation (SequenceStartNumber, SequenceEndNumber, AllocatedFor) 
VALUES (%d, %d, 'CustomerABC')
```

This way we have a running list of these blocks of numbers, and who's using them.

This works fine as-is, except it's obviously apparent this method cannot account for concurrency. Hypothetically ( it hasn't happened yet ) two simultaneous processes could perform the first query at the same time and grab the same starting number.

What would be the best way to re-factor this, to block the table before the insert clause is done? Should this operation be formed into a stored procedure somehow? SQL is not my strongest suit, so thus I have to ask what might be rudimentary question to the rest of you. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO dbo.SequenceNumberAllocation
(
  SequenceStartNumber, 
  SequenceEndNumber, 
  AllocatedFor
)
SELECT 
  MAX(SequenceEndNumber) + 1,
  MAX(SequenceEndNumber) + @HoweverManyNumbersYouNeed, 
  'Customer ABC'
FROM dbo.SequenceNumberAllocation WITH (HOLDLOCK);

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: Simple and effective. I said I was bad with SQL :) Thanks so much!

Comment: I wonder if the absence of ISNULL or COALESCE around the MAXes was what triggered the downvote. Not an issue when the table is guaranteed to already have rows, but otherwise...

Comment: @AndriyM thanks, I made the assumption because the OP posted existing rows in the question.